# Confusing words

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Voces denotent eventum quo factum est, videlicet, **ut id quod ad intelligendum ex consilio Dei propositum erat**, vel absconditum sit, id est, non acceptum cum intellectu & sensu; vel revelatum, id est, vera fide apprehensum

How would I translate the bolded part? Literally it is: "That what for understanding was purposed from the counsel of God." How can I make more sense of it?

Answer (score 5):

Simplified, the sentence reads:

> Voces denotent eventum, ut id, quod propositum erat, vel absconditum sit, vel revelatum.

That is: "Words shall indicate the event, so that that which was proposed is  hidden as well as revealed." (*vel...vel* can mean "X as well as Y," based on context I believe this is the case here).

*Absconditum* is explained thus: *id est, non acceptum cum intellectu & sensu* (that is, not understood with the intellect and sense)

*Revelatum* is explained as follows: *id est, vera fide apprehensum* (that is, grasped through true faith).

So all in all we end up with:

> The words shall of course indicate the event by which it was done, so that the part of God's purpose which was put forth to be understood is at once concealed, that is, not understood with the intellect and the senses, and revealed, that is, grasped through true faith.

"The event by which it was done" is rather clunky, more context might allow for a better translation.

Comment: can you comment on *quo* instead of *quibus*? I know sometimes a singular verb is used where the subject is plural, but also relative pronoun?

Comment: @d_e I believe the antecedent is *eventum*, which is singular.

Comment: i.e., "the event by which the [same] event was done"? I seem to be missing something. If *quo* refers to the *eventum*, then what is the subject of *factum est*?

Comment: @d_e something previously mentioned. As usual, Michael Yoo has dug up some arcane Latin that Google Books doesn't find, so that's my best guess.

Comment: I found it (probably). several parts were omitted in the question : https://books.google.es/books?id=twRlAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA69&lpg=RA1-PA69&dq=%22ut+id+quod+ad+intelligendum%22&source=bl&ots=1KKZjjvLPU&sig=ACfU3U3d3dgRNo6NTSXzCUoAnM2B8PqfBg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR75DMwar6AhUYhv0HHRQFAAgQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22ut%20id%20quod%20ad%20intelligendum%22&f=false